# How to send multiple requests simultaneously with dynamically changing resource in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to send multiple post requests simultaneously. And the problem is that transaction id in url should always be unique.
I added Synchronizing timer to send requests at once and added BeanShell PostProcessor to increment transaction id after request is sent. 
But this works only if requests are executed one by one. How to increment transaction id if I need to run requests all at once?
[image: url where txnId should be unique]

[image: this is the increment txnId script]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use __counter() function in "global" mode like `${__counter(FALSE,)}` instead of manually incrementing the "txnId" variable:

Demo:

[image: JMeter Counter]

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article for more information on generating incremented numeric values in JMeter.

Going forward remember that you need to implement some form of [inter-thread communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) to ensure that the same variable is not updated by 2 threads at the same time.